# Why does a read-only field in Django-rest-framework throw errors when posting data?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

In one of my models I would like to obtain the data-field as a list. To achieve this, I created a SerializerMethodField:

```
class testserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    testfield_as_list =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_testfield_as_list(self,obj):
        return [obj.testfield]
```

This works as expected when getting the data. When posting the data with a POST request, it also works eventually ( the data is arriving correctly when inspecting through the admin-panel). However, the response that I get is 500. In addition, the following error is thrown:

*in get_testfield_as_list return [obj.tesfield]*
'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'testfield'

I assume this has something to do with the fact that the data is not serialized correctly yet. What I find strange is that in the DRF documentation it is specified that the SerializerMethodField is a read-only field, so it should not do anything when posting data. Why is it throwing an error then?

Some additional info: I am using an upsert functionality for the items: only update the fields that changed:

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = testserializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUserOrReadOnly]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = testserializer(data=request.data,many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        test_object_list = [Test(**x) for x in serializer.validated_data]
 
        Test.objects.bulk_create(
            test_object_list, 
            update_conflicts=True,
            unique_fields=['unique_id'],
            update_fields=['category','description','testfield'])

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            headers=headers
        )


class Test(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
    
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    testfield = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

The full traceback:

> Internal Server Error: /api/v1/boards/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "folder\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55,  in
> inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "folder\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "folder\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "folder\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "folder\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "folder\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "folder\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in
> raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc   File "folder\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "....\api\views.py", line 33, in create
> headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)   File "folder\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 768, in  data
> ret = super().data   File "folder\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 255, in  data
> self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)   File "folder\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 686, in
> to_representation
> return [   File "folder\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 687, in  
> self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable   File "folder\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 522, in
> to_representation
> ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)   File "folder\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1838, in to_representation
> return method(value)   File "....\api\serializers.py", line 12, in get_testfield_as_list   return [obj.testfield] AttributeError:
> 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'testfield'

Comment: Can you post your full traceback?

Comment: Yes, I just added it to the question!